# ngbRadioGroup click event triggered after ngModel update in IE11

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm using a `ngbRadioGroup` and each of the inputs within the radio group has a click event so that the input can be deselected:

```
<div ngbRadioGroup class="btn-group-toggle" name="myGroup" [(ngModel)]="myModel" [disabled]="this.hasSubmittedAnswer">
    <label ngbButtonLabel *ngFor="let choice of currentActivity.choices" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg mr-2">
        <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="choice" (click)="onAnswerSelected(choice)"> {{ choice }}
    </label>
</div>
```

In Chrome 73 the click event fires before the model is updated. In IE11 "myModel" is updated before "onAnswerSelected" fires.

Is there any way I can get the event to fire before the model is updated in IE11?

Comment: did you ever got this working? I tried to use `ngModelChange` but there are some css problems popping up.

Comment: Sorry I don't think so, as my code is the same and I can't even remember the problem it was causing lol.